# Two adverbs, and an indefinite article

Tags: word-usage, adverbs, articles, syntactic-analysis

I found two adverbs, between which indefinite article, in [TVTRopes site](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/LaughingAtYourOwnJokes):

> - Upon reading it, the host concludes that it's **actually a really** old joke that everyone knows.

Is it grammatical to use two adverbs in the way used above? I think, it should have been like this:

> - Upon reading it, the host concludes that it's **actually** a old joke that everyone knows.

Or, like this one:

> - Upon reading it, the host concludes that it's **really** a old joke that everyone knows.

I also found the same usage of adverbs, barring indefinite article in [Bustle site](https://www.bustle.com/p/4-zodiac-signs-that-seem-tough-on-the-outside-but-are-actually-really-sensitive-9930243):

> - Here are four zodiac signs that seem tough on the outside, but **actually really** sensitive, according to astrologers.

Comment: "Is it grammatical to use two adverbs in the way used above?" Why do you think not?

Comment: The Q is based on a misconception.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it grammatical to use two adverbs in the way used above?

Yes, it is absolutely grammatical.

Your confusion seems to come from the idea that both adverbs modify the same thing, but they do not.

*Really* modifies the adjective *old*, as in

> It is a *really* old joke.

*Actually*, however, modifies the verb *is*, as in

> It *actually* is an old joke.

The fact that the verb and the adjective are inverted (which is fine, it happens a lot) just has as an effect that both adverbs end up closer to one another, but they still do not modify the same part of the sentence. *If* the adverb *actually* would modify *a really old joke*, it would end up *after* the article:

> It is an actually really old joke.

This would be grammatical, but it doesn't sound very natural.

Your proposed alternative changes the meaning of the sentence:

> Upon reading it, the host concludes that it's really a old joke that everyone knows.

In this case, *really* modifies the verb *is*, as in

> Upon reading it, the host concludes that it really is an old joke that everyone knows.